# Can I send push message for 2 topics? FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

For example for users, who subscribed to topics `cats` and `dogs` at the same time? like

```
'condition': "'cats' in topics && 'dogs' in topics"
```

But I want to send a notification from firebase console, not from the backend server.

Comment: I'm checking it out right now and I think your observation is correct that you can only send to a single topic from the console. If you get a chance, can you file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/)? I'm happy to do it on your behalf as well and I'm still going to send the feedback to the team, but it helps to hear directly from developers :)

Comment: Also I filed a feature request, hah